# Store image files with RoboMongo(now Robo 3T)

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I want to store image files using RoboMongo GUI. I can't find how to do this.
I know using GridFS, it is possible to store images in MongoDb. But how to do it in RoboMongo. 
Does RoboMongo support GridFS?